# Is the OWNER in ALL_CONSTRAINTS and ALL_CONS_COLUMNS the same as the table owner?

Tags: oracle, constraints, data-dictionary

According to Oracle, the `OWNER` field in `(ALL|USER|DBA)_CONSTRAINTS` is the owner of the constraint.  To relate back to the table that this constraint belongs to, this view provides `TABLE_NAME`, however to uniquely identify a table, I need both the table's owner and the table name.  Because the `*_CONSTRAINTS` and `*_ALL_CONS_COLUMNS` views do not have a `TABLE_OWNER` field, does this mean that the constraint owner is the same as the table owner?  Or in other words, can a constraint only be added by the owner of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean that the constraint owner is the same as the table owner?

Yes.

---

> can a constraint only be added by the owner of the table?

No, it can be added by another user that has `alter any table` privileges. One of such is `SYS`. Here's an example:

Connected as Scott, I'm creating a table:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.
```

Connect as SYS and alter Scott's table - add primary key constraint:

```
SQL> connect sys as sysdba

Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> alter table scott.test add constraint pk_test primary key (id);

Table altered.
```

Back to Scott, to check who owns what:

```
SQL> select constraint_name, owner from all_constraints where table_name = 'TEST';

CONSTRAINT_NAME                OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
PK_TEST                        SCOTT

SQL> select table_name, owner From all_tables where table_name = 'TEST';

TABLE_NAME                     OWNER
------------------------------ ------------------------------
TEST                           SCOTT

SQL>
```

As you can see, Scott owns *everything*.